# generated path does not match custom route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes, custom-routes

(Rails 4.2)
I have a miss-match of routes that's in the routes.rb file vs the  generated from my page. What is it I am doing wrong?
This is the raked route I want to access :

```
see_hint_deck_card_tracker GET    /decks/:deck_id/cards/:card_id/trackers/:id/see_hint(.:format) trackers#see_hint
```

I am actually taken to what I think is the correct url, but it tells me I don't have a route for this page:

```
http://localhost:3000/decks/9/cards/2/trackers/1/see_hint
```

I have the following routes:

```
   resources :decks do
    resources :cards do
      resources :trackers do
        member do
          get 'see_hint'
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

app/controllers/tracker_controller.rb :

```
class TrackerController < ApplicationController
    def show_hint
      puts 'we found this'
    end
end
```

inside my /decks/:id/cards/:id/show I have this link_to: (get_tracker, calls for a helper method to get the correct tracker)

```
<%= link_to "Reveal Hint", see_hint_deck_card_tracker_path(@card.deck, @card, get_tracker), id: "reveal_hint_button"  %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your error message is probably telling you you don't have a *Controller* for that route, not that the *Route* is missing. This is because you're using the plural `resources` in your `routes.rb`, but your controller name is singular:

```
# Your Code:
resources :trackers
controller TrackerController

# Expected Code:
resources :trackers
controller TrackersController
                 ^^^
```

You'll also want to make sure your controller is available at `app/controllers/trackers_controller.rb` (note the plurality).

Comment: Shoot. Redo the controller so the grammar matches!

Comment: Destroy Controller, than re-generate in Plural. Works!